# MyISAM tables are better then InnoDB tables for full text searching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, myisam

Between MyISAM and InnoDB tables, which will be better for full text searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Innodb is a better choice as MYISAM is really old engine and would fade away in near future. You can look into sphinx with Innodb or just migrate to MYSQL 5.6 the new stable release by MYSQL to take advantage of new Innodb full text search feature and it is quite comparable to sphinx.